# Delete row if previous cell in column is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column with lots of blank cells, and for every blank cell I would like to delete the row that included the blank cell as well as the row beneath it. It's deleting every row beneath a blank cell that's proved tricky for me.

Comment: Share your attempts please.

Comment: can you post code examples of what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search column A you can then use this code to remove all rows with blank cells and the row beneath that one. The code searches from bottom to top as you should do when you are deleting rows, in order not to skip any rows.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    For i = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete '~~> Removes the blank row
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete '~~> Removes the row that were under the blank row
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There was another answer posted a few minutes ago that was close to the right answer. I modified it to use recursion, and the few test scenarios I tried seem to work. The trick was getting it to work with multiple blank lines.

```
Public Sub DeleteBlanks(rng As Range)
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    EvaluateCell cell
Next cell
End Sub

Public Sub EvaluateCell(cell As Range)
If cell.Value = "" Then
    If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        EvaluateCell cell.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        cell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End Sub

Sub Testing()
DeleteBlanks Selection
End Sub
```